# Setting a raw data source into mediaplayer singleton

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am having a shot at setting a mediaplayer as a singleton so that it can be controlled from various activities in my project. Much research has led me to the following code.

```
if (current_player == null)
{
    try
    {
        current_player = MusicPlayer.getInstance();
        AssetFileDescriptor afd = this.getResources().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.mytune);
        current_player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor());
        current_player.prepare();
        current_player.setLooping(true);
        current_player.start();
        afd.close();
}
catch (IllegalArgumentException e) { Log.e("IllegalArgumentException", "error: " + e.getMessage(), e);   } 
catch (IllegalStateException e) {Log.e("IllegalStateException", "error: " + e.getMessage(), e); } 
catch (IOException e) {Log.e("IOException", "error: " + e.getMessage(), e); } 
catch (Exception e){    Log.e("Main media player", "error: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
```

I do know that
1. the MediaPlayer is being created
2. the AssetFileDescriptor is for the correct file

The code fails at the .setDataSource line with an IOException
error: setDataSourceFD failed.: status=0x80000000

The code is deliberately similar to many examples shown on various forums that claim it should work.
To be clear I have proven that

```
current_player= MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.mytune);
```

works fine.

I would be very grateful for any suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the file in the directory **assets**. Сorrect line **AssetFileDescriptor afd =...** on

```
AssetFileDescriptor afd = context.getAssets().openFd(fileName);
current_player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength() );
```

Comment: You solved the problem for me. The file can be in the res/raw directory OK. The issue is you must use  .setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength() );